# Should I be banned from chat by a moderator from another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, chat

So, I've just been banned by a non-gaming mod for stating something in chat that **wasn't flagged**, which was along the lines of: "being @ChrisHatez should be a bannable offense.", in a playful string of others stating "X should be a bannable offense."

For this, I was banned for 60 minutes. I wasn't going to complain but then a few moments later the ban got updated to two hours:

> your account has been temporarily suspended by a moderator and cannot chat for 1 hour 59 minutes.

First of all, what right does a **non-gaming mod** have coming into the gaming channel and banning people for things that **weren't flagged**.

Secondly, as many people who *are* related to gaming know, I fully ignore people I actually don't like and therefore my comment can be taken as playful banter. Sure, somebody could see it as not playful and therefore I was willing to sit out for the hour ban without comment, however the escalation (which was manual, since my screen refreshed multiple times during the process) is prompting this.

As this is my first ban for this particular subject, and indeed the first ban I've had in a while:

- Please explain why a comment that wasn't flagged resulted in a ban
- Please explain why the ban was then removed and readded with a longer duration

Explain why I should have to tolerate sexist comments, general abuse, comments about feminism, a whole variety of comments directly insulting me (most of which the user in question deleted by themselves before they could be flagged), and yet when I make a single playful comment I get a two hour ban?

Comment: As I said on chat, what you said was uncalled for and pushing it. So, a simple half an hour to an hour (given your history of dancing the line a bit) would've been reasonable, imo. Elevating it to two hours when you cut it down after a warning was not really necessary.

Comment: If @ChrisHateZ truly feels that he is being attacked by kalina, someone should show him how the ignore feature works.

Comment: Your message was flagged.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot: The ignore user feature isn't intended to ignore a user you believe is harassing you. That's one of the reasons chat flags exist.

Comment: Your message was "flagged for moderator", rather than the normal offensive flag.

Comment: @Wipqozn I disagree.  That's exactly what the ignore feature is for.  Whether or not a flag is also an appropriate action is not part of my claim.

Comment: @StrixVaria if it was flagged for mod, I'd still have the message linking to the content that was flagged.

Comment: @kalina The mod probably deleted the message along with whatever other actions he took.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I was the mod who banned you.

Firstly, it *was* flagged. It was not an offensive flag, it was a private flag, so only mods can see it.

My reasoning behind the ban: You and Chris have been warned many, *many* times about fighting.

I understand calmly defending yourself from attacks from Chris. I will not, however, tolerate personal attacks. Especially between two people who have a history of fighting with each other. I clarified my stance on this earlier today. Your comment would only serve to provoke him and had the potential to start another fight, besides being a personal attack. I deleted it, and applied a 2 hour ban (well, I accidentally used the default 1 hour ban and then upped it) because this was something you've been warned about many, many times.

> Explain why I should have to tolerate sexist comments, general abuse, comments about feminism, a whole variety of comments directly insulting me (most of which the user in question deleted by themselves before they could be flagged), and yet when I make a single playful comment I get a two hour ban?

Sexist comments? General abuse? Flag 'em, and tell the user to stop. Chris has been banned a couple of times for these anyway, I think that happened twice today morning.

> First of all, what right does a non-gaming mod have coming into the gaming channel

Because chat is moderated by all mods from the network. While the room community can set the tone, personal attacks and aggressive fighting are not allowed anywhere in chat. That's something we can enforce without the need of being moderators on Gaming.

Finally, [from the chat faq](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#nice):

> ### Do I have to be nice?
>
> Yes. We expect community members to treat each other with respect …
> even when they don't deserve it.
>
> This site is collectively moderated by the community through
> participatory flagging. If your chat messages are repeatedly being
> flagged by your peers you might find yourself muted, banned, or – in
> extreme cases – your The Stack Exchange Network reputation may be
> negatively affected.
>
> If you see an inappropriate, spam, or offensive chat message, please
> use the hover menu at the far right of each chat message to flag it.
> This will draw it to the attention of the community moderators.

Comment: kalina contacted SE support about this. After reviewing the chat logs, it's clear that neither of these users was behaving in a way conducive to a pleasant experience for anyone else in the room. They can both sit out for a day unless one of the Gaming mods feels like letting them back in.

Comment: @Shog9 Alright, thanks for looking into this.

Comment: @Shog9 & Manish, thank you for your assistance. All I can bring to the table is my apologies for my blissful absence from chat today despite the various ping from Teacher's Lounge updating me about the situation, all due to a variety of reasons including an exam, possibly getting myself a thesis and watching [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-VY7SPt9Ng&feature=player_detailpage#t=177s). It's good to know that there's still people willing to chime in when mods are sleeping and "ponies" are being posted. All the mods who intervened today have my gratitude, and possibly this community's too.

Comment: @badp You don't need to apologize, we all have real life to worry about. And it's not exactly your duty as a mod to monitor Gaming chat, either. Hope the exam went well! :)

Comment: @One-One Yeah, it's weird. I got a gold badge. On a meta. Of a site I don't participate in. O_0